# How to hide an element if it does not fit in a flex layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a horizontal flexbox div that has 3 items. Each has a min-width, and I want to hide them as the screen gets too small to fit them. If I knew the width of all 3 divs, I would just use media queries to hide the divs at the right breakpoints. The problem is that div1 is an image with dynamic width (recreated in example with random width)

Is there any way to hide an element if it doesn't fit into the flexbox container?

Its kind of hard to explain but hopefully running this code snippet a few times will show what I'm after:

```js
let width = (Math.random()*600)
document.getElementById('one').style.minWidth = width + 'px'
```

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.three {
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div id="one" class="one">
    unknown width
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    hide me if im off the screen
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    hide me if im off the screen
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats what im doing, div1 in the example is the img, the problem is that the width varies depending on the photo dimentions (basically random) so I'm basically trying to do a media query on the remaining space

Comment: If yo use `flex-wrap: wrap` can you avoid having to hide them?

Comment: flex-wrap is pretty close! but i need to hide them instead of spill over

Comment: @dippas the image needs to be fully displayed with a fixed height and auto width and the other two should only be displayed if there is enough room

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have a fixed height image, you can set `root` to a maximum height and use `flex-wrap: wrap`.

```js
let width = (Math.random()*600)
document.getElementById('one').style.minWidth = width + 'px'
```

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  max-height:50px;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.two {
  min-width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.three {
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div id="one" class="one">
    unknown width
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    hide me if im off the screen
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    hide me if im off the screen
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4y39h8jn/1/

Comment: How can I add an element after the last one? Let's say there will be displayed 4/10 and I want to add an element of the same shape with three dots.